# Where do I get nuget.exe 3.0+?

Tags: nuget, visual-studio-2015

Supposedly, nuget 3.0 has been released. VS2015 ships with 3.0 baked in. However, `NuGet.CommandLine` seems to be stuck at 2.8.6 (https://www.nuget.org/packages/NuGet.CommandLine) which means products like TeamCity won't upgrade to 3.0.

Where can I find the nuget for nuget 3.0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Teamcity now is properly integrated with NuGet 3.x. You can follow the following steps to install a specific version: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/NuGet#NuGet-InstallingNuGettoTeamCityagents

Answer (score 6):

There's no command line for v3 yet, although they plan to release it soon, as the discussion in the [NuGet 3.0 Released](http://blog.nuget.org/20150720/nuget-3.0.0.html#comment-2155060213) blog post implies.

However, you can download the 3.1.0 beta, if you want, from here: http://dist.nuget.org/win-x86-commandline/v3.1.0-beta/nuget.exe

Comment: Unfortunately TeamCity insists on the nuget for it. :/

Comment: The solution [here](https://johanleino.wordpress.com/2013/06/10/using-teamcity-to-enable-nuget-package-restore-for-solution-level-packages/) worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

Nuget can update itself by the command line:

```
nuget.exe update -self
```

Reference:

- https://docs.nuget.org/ndocs/guides/install-nuget#nuget-cli

Comment: Thanks. That's good information, but it doesn't answer the question about where you can download it.

Comment: Maybe... You were looking for a solution to "upgrade Nuget for products like TeamCity". I was looking for the same thing for Jenkins and it helped me. Hope it helps others too. Also, the link mentioned in your answer are not stucked in 2.8.6 anymore (thats why `update -self` works).